# Appending rows returned from different queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, append

I am having 3 queries, which takes data from 3 different tables (with joins) and their column names are pretty much same (or I made them same by using `AS`keyword). Once the 3 queries are completed, I want to combine their results, so it looks like they are coming from one table. Please have a look at the below codes.

**1st Query**

```
SELECT Client_Portfolio.*,
Client.Name,
Provider.Name,
"One" AS Income_Type,
One.`One_Gross_Fee` AS "Gross_Fee",
One.`One_V_Fee` AS "V_Fee",
One.`One_E_Fee` AS "E_Fee",
One.`One_I_Fee` AS "I_Fee",
One.`One_Tax_Provision` AS "Tax_Provision",
One.`One_Net_Income` AS "Net_Income",
"N/A" AS VAT,
One.`Updated_Date`
FROM Client_Portfolio
INNER JOIN Portfolio ON Portfolio.`idPortfolio` = Client_Portfolio.`idPortfolio`
INNER JOIN Client ON Client.idClient = Client_Portfolio.idClient
JOIN Provider ON Provider.idProvider = Portfolio.idProvider
INNER JOIN One ON One.idPortfolio = Portfolio.idPortfolio
```

**2nd Query**

```
SELECT Client_Portfolio.*,
Client.Name,
Provider.Name,
"Two" AS Income_Type,
Two.`Two_Gross_Fee` AS "Gross_Fee",
Two.`Two_V_Fee` AS "V_Fee",
Two.`Two_E_Fee` AS "E_Fee",
Two.`Two_I_Fee` AS "I_Fee",
Two.`Two_Tax_Provision` AS "Tax_Provision",
Two.`Two_Net_Income` AS "Net_Income",
Two.`Two_Vat` AS VAT,
Two.`Updated_Date`
FROM Client_Portfolio
INNER JOIN Portfolio ON Portfolio.`idPortfolio` = Client_Portfolio.`idPortfolio`
INNER JOIN Client ON Client.idClient = Client_Portfolio.idClient
JOIN Provider ON Provider.idProvider = Portfolio.idProvider
INNER JOIN Two ON Two.idPortfolio = Portfolio.idPortfolio
```

**3rd Query**

```
SELECT Client_Portfolio.*,
Client.Name,
Provider.Name,
"Three" AS Income_Type,
Three.`Three_Gross_Fee` AS "Gross_Fee",
"N\A" AS "V_Fee",
Three.`Three_E_Fee` AS "E_Fee",
"N\A" AS "I_Fee",
Three.`Three_Tax_Provision` AS "Tax_Provision",
Three.`Three_Net_Income` AS "Net_Income",
Three.`Three_Vat` AS VAT,
Three.`Updated_Date`
FROM Client_Portfolio
INNER JOIN Portfolio ON Portfolio.`idPortfolio` = Client_Portfolio.`idPortfolio`
INNER JOIN Client ON Client.idClient = Client_Portfolio.idClient
JOIN Provider ON Provider.idProvider = Portfolio.idProvider
INNER JOIN Three ON Three.idPortfolio = Portfolio.idPortfolio
```

Once these queries are done, I want to combine their results. Which means, Rows returned by the **2nd Query** will be appended after the rows returned by the **1st query.** Rows returned by the 3rd query will be appended after the rows returned by the 2nd query. Finally, I want to sort the final result by `Updated_Date`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION` to combine the queries:

```
SELECT one_fields FROM Client_Portfolio ...
UNION
SELECT two_fields FROM Client_Portfolio ...
UNION
SELECT three_fields FROM Client_Portfolio ...
```

Sorting can be done by appending an order by clause after the last query, as follows:

```
SELECT one_fields FROM Client_Portfolio ...
UNION
SELECT two_fields FROM Client_Portfolio ...
UNION
SELECT three_fields FROM Client_Portfolio ...
ORDER BY field1, field2, field3...;
```

Note that `field1`, `field2`... can be field names or field numbers (starting from 1).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. what about the sorting part?

Comment: I know I have to use `Order By` bu where?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `ORDER BY Income_Type, Updated_Date`.

Comment: For performance, use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` - unless the individual queries do produce duplicates, which you want to preserve.