# Calling all the DB queries at once VS calling DB queries one by one

Tags: java, database, swing, user-interface, jdbc

I am having a big question in my mind. Here is the situation.

I have a `JTabbedPane` where there are 5 tabs in it. All 5 tabs contain `JTables`, all tables are feeded from the data retrieved from the database. All these tables will display data related to a "particular" year, therefore I have a `JComboBox` with years in it.

I have allocated `ComponentListeners` to all the tabs, so whenever a tab is "visible", it will call the database and update the table inside the tab. Just like below.

```
private class DisplayAllRevenue extends ComponentAdapter {
     @Override
     public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {

     }
}

private class DisplayCompetitorRevenue extends ComponentAdapter {
     @Override
     public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {

     }
}

private class DisplayMonthRevenue extends ComponentAdapter {
     @Override
     public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {

     }
}
```

Now, in one of my previous questions, a S.O user told me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26911428/1379286) this will make heavy database calls because the tables are calling the database every time a tab is selected. Therefore, I am thinking about removing the `ComponentListeners` and updating all the tables once the user selects a date from the `JComboBox`.

Will this be subjected to heavy database traffic? What if I run it in another thread??? Normally, my DB queries are like this - > [Appending rows returned from different queries into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26944736/appending-rows-returned-from-different-queries-into-one)

what is your advice on this?

Comment: Think about it this way.  What happens if a user never opens one of the tabs? *"Now, in one of my previous questions, a S.O user told me here this will make heavy database calls because the tables are calling the database every time a tab is selected"* ... as opposed to calling them all at one?  Why not cache the results (after they have been loaded) until a key factor has changed (ie a filter) or the user refreshes them...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Then it is useless to load that tab's data?

Comment: Exactly.  We had a similar problem, where we were loading multiple tabs of data, but it was unlikely that, on a day to day bases, that many of the users would need most of that data.  We choose to implement a lazy loading approach to the problem, only physically loading the data for the tabs as they were needed, caching the results until either a key filter element changed or the user refreshed the data for the tab...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: You mean you loaded data \tab by tab? I am refreshing it everytime bcs user might enter data into the system and visit tabs to see the "just" entered data..

Comment: As needed, yep. Consider this, the amount of work it will take to load the data for ALL the tabs as opposed for each individual tabs as need is probably the same.  It might be argued you could use a single connection to do all of them, but you could do the same thing for the lazy loading approach, the benefit you get, is your program "appears" to be faster, because you're not waiting for data you might not see to be loaded (and the overhead that the components might introduce as they are updated as well)

Comment: To be fair I didn't know the actual goal of attaching a `ComponentListener` to the component as it is clearly stated in this question when I did that comment. I didn't even know it is placed in a tabbed pane just because [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26908487/1795530) did not provide enough context to know that. Now I agree with a lazy-loading approach that could be implemented either by using `ComponentListener` or by attaching a `ChangeListener` to the tabbed pane. In any case I'd insist in using a `SwingWorker` to do database calls in a separate thread. @MadProgrammer

Comment: @dic19 Agreed, a ChangeListener would be a better choice and a SwingWorker would be the right approach